# Explanation about RXJS operator "withLatestFrom"

Tags: angular, rxjs, operators

Can someone explain what does `withLatestFrom` do? I read the documentation but I'm not sure I understood.
Thank you

Comment: Please, cite the documentation you read, and tell us what part of it you did not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`withLatestFrom` reads the value from a different stream but it does not initiate the observable stream itself.

An example:

```
a$.pipe(
  withLatesFrom(b$),
).subscribe(([a, b]) => console.log(a, b));
```

Every time `a$` emits, it will query/read the `b$` value to be used downstream. Notice, however, that if `b$` emits, the observable stream does not emit/process.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is very clear :)